# Best practice check GET or POST is set and not empety in PHP5

Tags: php

Just wondering is the following best practice to check if a `$_GET` or `$_POST` is set?

```
if(isset($_GET['input']) && !empty($_GET['input']))

if(isset($_POST['input']) && !empty($_POST['input']))
```

If its not, what's the best practice to do?

Comment: Depends on use case right? For a lot of stuff, no need to check at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean, it exists and has a value, then, for strings

```
if (isset($_GET['foo']) && strlen($_GET['foo'])) {   }
```

using both isset() and !empty() is redundant, you could just use !empty(). make sure you understand what empty() does, its often misunderstood.

on second thought, adding a type check may be a good idea for the general case, considering request variables can be arrays too. Otherwise unintended functionality could result.

```
if (isset($_GET['foo']) && is_string(($_GET['foo']) && strlen($_GET['foo'])) {   }
```

Comment: How is it redundant? `empty()` can return true while `isset()` doesn't.

Comment: @ccKep and thats exactly what makes the use off isset redudant, because you could have just used empty. there is no case where isset returns false, yet empty returns true.

Comment: @ccK Yep, you fall into the category of people that misunderstand `empty` and should read the aforelinked guide. :-3

Comment: @chris Uhm... If `isset == false` then `empty == true`... Otherwise agree though. ;)

Comment: @chris: "there is no case where isset returns false, yet empty returns true" `var_dump(array(isset($c), empty($c)));`  where $c is undefined.

Comment: @ccK Yes, he messed up the statement there, should be *"there's no case where `isset` and `empty` both return `false`"*. It's still redundant.

Comment: adding a type check would be a useless idea

Comment: an empty array doesn't have a value, yet it's strlen() is 5. type check prevents a false positive.

Comment: You have a syntax error there, `&& is_string(($_GET['foo'])` should be `&& is_string($_GET['foo'])`